# Closed/disable/pause application in a certain time interval

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, global-asax, app-offline.htm

I have an asp.net webform app.

I don't want users to use the whole app in the weekend (from Friday 6pm to Sunday 23:59:59pm everyweek)

What I normally do is that on Friday I put a special asp.net file named "app_offline.htm" on the root and the whole app now only display content of the "app_offline.htm" (which normally saying: "Sorry, we are currently under maintenance, please check back later") and I delete that file on Sunday evening. That's totally inefficient.

Is there anyway I can put a global rule or something to disable the app (or just display/redirect to a only page that say something: "Sorry, we are currently under maintenance, please check back later" on that time interval?

I use Masterpage, for those pages that are under a Masterpage, I can put a rule on page_load event in the Masterpage but there are a lot of pages that are not under any Masterpage and I dont want to go to single one of them to put the rule on.

Comment: why don't you check what day it is and what time and make some if's when true redirect.

Comment: How about placing a method to your master page's Page Load that allows you to check for certain days of the week. If the conditions didn't satisfy you, you can force the page to be redirected to your "maintenance" page.